# reload static IP ubuntu 16

Tags: networking, 16.04, static-ip

I am using Ubuntu server 16.04 and setting up some network interfaces, I wish to reload a static IP after changing its address at /etc/network/interfaces without reboot:

```
auto ens6
iface ens6 inet static
        address 192.168.0.41
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

I tried the following:

```
sudo systemctl restart networking
sudo ifconfig ens6 down (and afterwards up)
sudo ifdown ens6 (and afterwards up)
```

and tried some combinations of these commands,

Yet if i change my 'address' at the /etc/network/interfaces it will get updated (at ifconfig) only after i reboot my machine

What is the correct way to do this action without a reboot?

EDIT - tried this also due to comments

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` for network restart?

Comment: tried now, seems like it's doing the same as 'systemctl restart networking', i still get the same IP address when checking ifconfig

Comment: OK, thanks for trying.  Unfortunately at the moment my system is not in a state that I could do some testing for you.   I can do some more research and see if I can duplicate the issue and help you resolve it.

Comment: thank you, ill keep an eye on the post, right now the servers are at setup and dev so I can manage with the reboots but i might need to change the static IP sometime at production and I can't afford rebooting for this type of action

Comment: One other thing you could try, and I just did this, when you run the `sudo ifdown ens6` try running `sudo ifup -a` to bring it back up and see if your IP address changes.  It just did for me.

Comment: sudo ip addr flush ens6 && sudo systemctl restart networking.service according to http://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/ubuntu-set-static-ip-address/

Answer (score 10):

If the ifdown+ifup approach isn't working, try:

```
sudo ifdown <network interface> && sudo ip addr flush <network interface> && sudo ifup <network interface>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ip addr flush enp0s3 && systemctl restart networking.service
```

Where `enp0s3` is your netcard name.

Answer (score 2):

To get your IP addresses to change without rebooting the system, run the following lines to perform the task.  Make sure that you have completed your changes to your `/etc/network/interfaces` file before you run these steps:

**EDIT:**

You can try turning off predictive network naming by adding the following to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="net.ifnames=0"
```

Then run the `grub` update:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot the system:

```
sudo reboot
```

---

Turn off the interface first:

```
sudo ifdown <network interface>
```

Then bring back up all interfaces:

```
sudo ifup -a
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this did not work for me i still get the same results at ifconfig (i am using ubuntu 16.04 lts)

Comment: @MatanLevy You know, I am wondering if it is the fact that I am not running predictive names for the network.  Unfortunately, I am not 100% sure if the Server edition uses predictive naming or not.  I am running 16.04.1 LTS.

Comment: tried to change the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and still no good

Comment: @MatanLevy Sorry, I forgot to mention that you have to reboot after changing that line and updating grub.   Did you reboot?

Comment: @MatanLevy Well, I did more testing, and mine is working fine.  I am going to have to install server edition then to fully test this out.

Comment: well i did not reboot, i will check this soon and let you know

Comment: @Terrance All Ubuntu 16.04 use predictive names unless explicitly disabled after installing.

Comment: @ThomasWard I wasn't quite certain because my Dell tower I use at work, I did a clean install of 16.04 on it, and it never setup predictive names on it.  Either way I tried, it still showed `em1` as my ethernet.  Just thought that one was interesting.

Comment: well i dont know why but that still ain't working

Comment: OK so it seems like this is working on my ubuntu servers (was trying on my ubuntu desktop) but not on my ubuntu desktop